# Why does socket read does not leave loop?

Tags: php, sockets

I have a socket client that would read data from the server.

However, it does not leave the do..while loop as soon as there are no more data left to read? why is that so? Thanks

```
while (true)
{
    $data_old=$data;
    $data = file_get_contents("userInput.txt");

        if($data_old != $data)
        {
            socket_write($socket, $data, strlen($data));
            do
            {
                $line =@socket_read($socket,2048);
                echo $line. "\n";
            }
            while($line != "");
        }

}
```

Comment: Because when you do read you expect there to be data? Use some kind of end flag or something so that read knows to stop or send an empty message.

Comment: apparently socket_read() should return ("") when there is no more data to be read.

Comment: You have an infinite loop or it just blocks on socket_read after last non-empty data received?

Comment: Have you tried to remove the error suppression operator and see what comes out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it using another method. By my server sending a (" ") statement to the client after all the data has been sent.

Client side will then exit that loop upon receiving the statement.

```
while (true)
{
    $data_old=$data;
    $data = file_get_contents("userInput.txt");

        if($data_old != $data)
        {
            socket_write($socket, $data, strlen($data));
            do
            {
                $line =@socket_read($socket,2048);
                if($line != " ")
                echo $line. "\n";
            }
            while($line != " ");
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem is that the execution never leaves the `while (true)` loop and not the `while($line != "")` one, try this:

```
while (true)
{
    $data_old = $data;
    $data = file_get_contents('userInput.txt');

    if ($data_old != $data)
    {
        socket_write($socket, $data, strlen($data));

        while (true)
        {
            $line = @socket_read($socket, 2048);

            echo $line. "\n";

            if ($line == '')
            {
                break 2;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is the socket is non-blocking you may also want to use [`socket_select()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-select.php) with a timeout.

Comment: no does not work..it still does not enter the ($line =='') block

Comment: @Jonathan: What happens if you remove the `@` from the `socket_read()` call?